# How to add Pull To Refresh at app launch?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, pull-to-refresh

At app launch,the UITableView automatic pull to refresh without any scroll.

Any tips or advices?

Comment: I use [EGOTableViewPullRefresh](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh) to pull-to-refresh.

Answer (score 3):

I added a pull-to-refresh by following: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2009/12/how-to-make-a-pull-to-reload-tableview-just-like-tweetie-2/. On app launch just manually call your refresh function.

Answer (score 0):

There's a github project with a component that implements pull to refresh:

https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh